# Merge [pivotal-cloud-foundry] and [cloudfoundry]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[cloudfoundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudfoundry) - 1063 questions

[pivotal-cloud-foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivotal-cloud-foundry) - 36 questions

Questions in both tags refer to the same product "Cloud Foundry" by Pivotal Software. It comes in different licensing/hosting variants, which might have caused the duplicate tags.

A different project by SpringSource also used the same name, but it was replaced by the current one.

*Note: Pick one and merge the other into it. I don't mind either way!*

Answer (score -1):

The tags clearly refer to the same product, not only in the abstract but also in actual usage, so a merge and synonymization is definitely appropriate.

The only question is which tag to make the "primary" tag. Based on my cursory research, the product is primarily referred to as simply "Cloud Foundry", without the vendor name "Pivotal" or "Pivotal Software". I noted that it is rendered with spaces, as "Cloud Foundry", rather than a single word with CamelCase.

Therefore, I've chosen to make the [cloud-foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-foundry) the "primary" tag, with the others as synonyms of it.

## [cloud-foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-foundry) ← [pivotal-cloud-foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivotal-cloud-foundry)

## [cloud-foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-foundry) ← [cloudfoundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudfoundry)

---

There are also the tags [cloudfoundry-uaa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudfoundry-uaa), [sap-cloud-foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-cloud-foundry), and [cloud-foundry-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-foundry-bosh) (which is a synonym of [cf-bosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cf-bosh)). Those remain unchanged.

Comment: Note that Pivotal was purchased by VMWare and Cloud Foundry is now called Tanzu :). https://tanzu.vmware.com/pivotal

Comment: Ah, another good reason to avoid vendor names in tags, @HereticMonkey!

Comment: @HereticMonkey, to be precise, Cloud Foundry is now just one product under the Tanzu umbrella. It's called "VMware Tanzu Application Service for VMs". :)

Comment: See https://searchitoperations.techtarget.com/news/252482840/VMware-Tanzu-beta-project-melds-Cloud-Foundry-Kubernetes